# Find the min/max of rows with overlapping column values, create new column to represent the full range of both

Tags: pandas

I'm using Pandas DataFrames. I'm looking to identify all rows where both columns A and B == True, then represent in Column C the all points on other side of that intersection where only A or B is still true but not the other. For example:

```
   A     B     C    
 0 False False False
 1 True  False True
 2 True  True  True
 3 True  True  True
 4 False True  True
 5 False False False
 6 True  False False
 7 True  False False
```

I can find the direct overlaps quite easily:

```
 df.loc[(df['A'] == True) & (df['B'] == True), 'C'] = True
```

... however this does not take into account the overlap need.

I considered creating column 'C' in this way, then grouping each column:

```
 grp_a = df.loc[(df['A'] == True), 'A'].groupby(df['A'].astype('int').diff.ne(0).cumsum())
 grp_b = df.loc[(df['A'] == True), 'A'].groupby(df['A'].astype('int').diff.ne(0).cumsum())
 grp_c = df.loc[(df['A'] == True), 'A'].groupby(df['A'].astype('int').diff.ne(0).cumsum())
```

From there I thought to iterate over the indexes in grp_c.indices and test the indices in grp_a and grp_b against those, find the min/max index of A and B and update column C. This feels like an inefficient way of getting to the result I want though.

Ideas?

Comment: Is that your expected output dataframe?  Why are 6 and 7 column C False?

Comment: Column C is a representation of it. I really just need the indices of where C would be True. C 6 and 7 are False because 5 breaks the overlap (A & B == False).

Comment: So, why isn't 1 False?

Comment: Because 2 starts the overlap so C should be True for it due to the adjacency to the overlap.

Comment: Basically I need to find True values on either side of where A & B == True intersect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#Input df just columns 'A' and 'B'
df = df[['A','B']]
df['C'] = df.assign(C=df.min(1)).groupby((df[['A','B']].max(1) == 0).cumsum())['C']\
                                .transform('max').mask(df.max(1)==0, False)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
       A      B      C
0  False  False  False
1   True  False   True
2   True   True   True
3   True   True   True
4  False   True   True
5  False  False  False
6   True  False  False
7   True  False  False
```

#### Explanation:

First, create column 'C' with the assignment of minimum value, what this does is to ass True to C where both A and B are True.  Next, using

```
df[['A','B']].max(1) == 0 

0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
6    False
7    False
dtype: bool
```

We can find all of the records were A and B are both False.  Then we use `cumsum` to create a count of those False False records. Allowing us to create grouping of records with the False False recording having a count up until the next False False record which gets incremented.

```
(df[['A','B']].max(1) == 0).cumsum()


0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    1
5    2
6    2
7    2
dtype: int32
```

Let's group the dataframe with the newly assigned column C by this grouping created with cumsum.  Then take the maximum value of column C from that group.  So, if the group has a True True record, assign True to all the records in that group.  Lastly, use `mask` to turn the first False False record back to False.

```
df.assign(C=df.min(1)).groupby((df[['A','B']].max(1) == 0).cumsum())['C']\
                                .transform('max').mask(df.max(1)==0, False)

0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5    False
6    False
7    False
Name: C, dtype: bool
```

And, assign that series to df['C'] overwriting the temporarily assigned C in the statement.

```
df['C'] = df.assign(C=df.min(1)).groupby((df[['A','B']].max(1) == 0).cumsum())['C']\
                                .transform('max').mask(df.max(1)==0, False)
```

Comment: Ah, very nice! It definitely seems to get the trick done. Now I just need to tear it down and understand it better so I can explain it to myself. ;)

Comment: I will break it down when I get a moment.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thanks for the rescue on this!